# Move 2 columns of data to a different tab when status selected

Tags: google-apps-script

I am still a beginner at using apps scripts and my experience is limited. I have been trying to alter a script I got running for a similar task but am having trouble getting it to work, with a few changes.

What I am looking to achieve is when 'Yes' is selected in column Z on ProspectiveSites tab, to then move columns 15 and 24 to July 2019, into columns A and B, and to enter above the 'Total' row. This currently sits on row 28 but does move up or down the page as needed.

If at all possible I would like it to move based on the current month, ie it's now July so to move that July2019 tab, in August to move to August2019 and so on.

I get this error when trying to run the script;
TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")

Here is a sample
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2nJ0A-GBqRFxtLl3tTk-AFzYQU-NU5w_gqYt5C4xVs/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (ss.getName() == 'ProspectiveSites' && e.range.getColumn() == 
26) {
    // Copy selected row to another sheet
    var targetSheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('July2019');
    var copyColumns = [15, 24];  // Column indices start with 1
    if (e.range.getValue() == 'Yes') {
      var row = e.range.getRow(), 
          targetData = [];
      var rowData = e.range.offset(0, 0, 1, 
    ss.getDataRange().getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      for (var i in rowData) {
        if (copyColumns.indexOf(parseInt(i) + 1) > -1) {
          targetData.push(rowData[i]);
        } else {
          targetData.push('');
        }
      }
      while (targetData[targetData.length - 1] == '') 
targetData.pop();
      Logger.log(rowData);
      Logger.log(targetData);
      row = targetSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1;
      targetSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 
targetData.length).setValues([targetData]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that the reason of your error message is due to directly running ``onEdit()`` with the script editor. If you want to run your script, how about editing a cell? When by this, the issue was changed, please update your question.

Comment: By the way, when I saw your shared Spreadsheet, I confirmed that there are several projects in the Spreadsheet, and those projects includes the function of ``onEdit()``. In this case, when a cell is edited, all functions of ``onEdit()`` in those projects are run. Please be careful this. If you test your script, I recommend to prepare new sample Spreadsheet and one project.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for the reply. I do not fully understand what you are saying. The various projects are automating different tasks which are all triggered by a value being entered in a watch column. How do I change this to work better?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't see the vision of your goal from your replying. I think that if you test the script, I recommend to prepare new sample Spreadsheet and one project which is a simple situation. If each ``onEdit()`` is completely independent, I think that you can test the script under the condition. But if unknown error occurs, it might make the debug be difficult. About this, I'm not sure because I have not completely checked your all projects. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Hi, ok I have made a new sample with on this project

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your current issue is to know the reason of the error message of ``TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. ``, you can see about it in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843615/move-2-columns-of-data-to-a-different-tab-when-status-selected?noredirect=1#comment100238870_56843615). If your current issue was changed, can you update your question by including more information?

Comment: in your original comment, I dont know what you mean by "how about editing a cell?"

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to fire the OnEdit event trigger, please edit manually a cell. By the way, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onEdit(e)` trigger [runs automatically when you change the value of any cell in the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite).

The `e` value that is passed to the function is an event object which provides the function information so it can respond. The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) in this case will contain in `{authMode=LIMITED, range=Range, source=Spreadsheet, user=username@domain.com, value=updatedvalue}` which you can see if you run `Logger.log(e)` in your `onEdit(e)` function.

It looks like you're trying to over-engineer this problem. In reality all you need to go is get the value for the row being edited by the Dropdown and copy the corresponding `O` and `X` cells to July2019 sheet:

```
function obtainFirstBlankRow() {  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('July2019');
  // search for first blank row
  var col = sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var vals = col.getValues();
  var count = 0;

  while (vals[count][0] != "") {
    count++;
  }
  return count + 1;
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (ss.getName() == 'ProspectiveSites' && e.range.getColumn() == 26) {

    if (e.range.getValue() != 'Yes'){
      return;
    }

    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ProspectiveSites');
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('July2019');

    var cell15 = sourceSheet.getRange('O' + e.range.getRow() + ':O' + e.range.getRow()).getValue();
    var cell24 = sourceSheet.getRange('X' + e.range.getRow() + ':X' + e.range.getRow()).getValue();

    var row = obtainFirstBlankRow();    
    targetSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(cell15);
    targetSheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(cell24);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rafa, I am really new at this and am struggling to comprehend. When I change the status in column Z nothing happens

Comment: I think I understand, are you wanting to copy the whole column into July2019, or just the cells in the corresponding column to the edited cell? So for example if you edit cell Z6 to say 'yes', do you then want the values of O6 and X6 to be copied to the July2019 sheet in the next available free row?

Comment: Hi, yes, just the corresponding column

Comment: @user10637952 I have updated my answer with some code which should do what you're looking for, I hope I've understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Hi, yes, that seems to be working perfectly now. Thanks so much for your help. Really appreciated